# getUserIdentityTokenAsync returning expired token

Tags: outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, office365-apps

I'm developing a Mail add-in for composing emails in Outlook 365. The Javascript web app calls getUserIdentityTokenAsync() to obtain an identity token, which is then validated with the app's C# backend web service. The identity token validation in the service is based almost entirely on [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ValidateIdentityToken).

On Wednesday last week I put up the app on a test server for a demo, and it worked as expected. This week when I go to use it I get this exception:

[image]

I tried logging out and logging back in but the error persists: why and how is this remedied?

EDIT:
I have caught it in the debugger, it's doing what it's supposed to, I just have to do some digging into why I'm getting these time values:
[image]

I guess judging by these values I can just increase the padding... but idk why it would work previously and not now??

[image]

EDIT2:

And now that I've updated the padding to be 10 minutes, I actually get back a legit claim that would've worked with the old code, but why the huge discrepancies between the "validFrom" and "now" times? It looks like they're not consistent, like the "validFrom" time fluctuates between ~5-10 minutes ahead or behind the current time.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the server where your code is running had an issue with it's time settings that got cleared up by a sync to an internet time server? The 5 minute padding is usually there to allow for slight discrepancies in time settings, since your server probably doesn't match exactly the time set on the Exchange server.

Comment: I think you're right, the server appears to be having inbound internet issues (and thus was having issues syncing the time).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the sample throws this error if the `nbf` claim in the token is later than they think it should be. How does the time in the error compare with the current time? I'm not sure if this is a bug in the sample or an issue with the token.